# deactivate if date expired trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

i want to be able to update the filed 'activated' to 0 when the 'expireDate' is before today.
can you show me how to do it with a triger? (i want to do this after the user insert the row)

```
id    expireDate       activated
1     2011-11-21       1
2     2011-04-22       1
```

Comment: Why are you duplicating data? Instead of selecting rows where activated = 1 or activated = 0, select rows where expireDate is greater or less than the current date. You do not need a second column representing this comparison. If you insist on having two columns for one bit of data, then determine the activated state in your application where you generate the INSERT query, there's no reason for a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

It will look something like this (tested on MySQL 5.1.37):

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT ON activity
  FOR EACH ROW
    IF NEW.deadline < CURDATE() THEN
      SET NEW.activity = 0;
    END IF
```

Comment: ok, i got it but...

keep getting a error on phpmyadmin:

    CREATE TRIGGER expierd
AFTER INSERT ON outlet
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
UPDATE outlet SET activated = 0 WHERE now() >= expireDate
END

    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 6

Comment: Apologies, I had some syntax errors. I also now tested this on MySQL 5.1.37; cheers.